# Symfony 4 - image dont load with assets

Tags: php, symfony4

In my app, I use Symfony 4 and I can't load assets! :( In my browser (Chrome) I don't see any images or css styles. Please help! Thanks! :D

My code:

```
{% for class in classes %}
Name: {{ class.name }}<br>
About: {{ class.aboutInfo }}<br>
Image: <br><img src="{{ class.photolocation }}"><br>
<a href="{{ path("mm_classes_remove", {'slug': class.id}) }}" style="color: 
#ff4455;">Delete</a><br><hr><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: did you run `encore` to build assets?

Comment: encore command? Please explain...

Comment: i run encore in the cli, and it gathers my assets, compiles css and js, and moves assets into the public folder

Comment: But.... how do you run? Can you install `encore` from `symfony/encore`? What commands do you use (I'm new in Sf....)